# What does the word "חַיִל" mean?

Tags: hebrew, rambam, etymology

Gideon was famously called "a Mighty Man of Valor" by the Malach/Messenger and the word is most famously utilized in Proverbs 31 in the description of the Virtuous Woman.
Doing research into the word [Chayil](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2428.htm), I came across Maimonides's commentary on [Exodus 18:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Exodus.18.21.1?ven=Commentary_on_the_Torah_by_Ramban_(Nachmanides)._Translated_and_annotated_by_Charles_B._Chavel._New_York,_Shilo_Pub._House,_1971-1976&lang=bi) in which he highlights alertness, wisdom, and fairness associated with the term.  My question is what does "חַיִל" mean?  Does the denotation only have to only do with courage, bravery, might as pertaining to some sort of battle?  Is there a connotation of substance (spiritual, mental, physical, wealth, prosperity, health, etc)?  For example, would somebody who has a joyous life and a loving family but is dirt poor be considered to have or be of Chayil? Does having the word "חַיִ" within the word give it a deeper meaning or add unto the definition as well? Todah Rabbah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chayil** חַיִל when used to describe a אֵֽשֶׁת־חַ֖יִל "Woman of Valor" in Mishlei / **Proverbs 31:10-30** alludes to a person full of חָכְמָ֑ה Wisdom, or  אִשָּׁ֥ה יִרְאַת־יְ֜הוָ֗ה **"G-d fearing"** Woman.

Valor is defined in Proverbs 31:10-30 as "G-d fearing" behavior in charitable servants of HaShem that provide food, necessities & wisdom for their community.

Comment: So would it be safe to say it describes someone who is full of courage and wisdom to do righteous and selfless acts?